# Xpath does not Work [Jasper JRXML]

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to use xpath for something simple but I'm not getting success.

I have the following XML:

```
 <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9ee0559e-6301-4cbe-b82b-2aa69bbe43c1">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<parameter name="Parameter1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString></jasperReport>
```

I'm trying to do this:
   `$queryString = $xml->xpath("/queryString");`

but this is returning array (0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a default namespace in your XML (http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports) so you will need to register it and use it to find any of the elements using XPath...

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );


$xml = <<<EOB
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9ee0559e-6301-4cbe-b82b-2aa69bbe43c1">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<parameter name="Parameter1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString></jasperReport>
EOB;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("d", "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports");
$queryString = $xml->xpath("//d:queryString");
print_r($queryString[0]->asXML());
```

In the code, I use a dummy prefix of d for the default namespace and then put this as part of the query.  Also note the use of // at the start - using a single / at the start of an XPath expression is assuming that it is a root element, // searches for any element.

The output is...

```
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
```